# SQL CLR stored procedure output

Tags: sql, clr, sqlclr

there is a simple class called User and List of its objects

```
  public class User
{
public int ID;
public string UserName;
public string UserPassword;
}
...
List userList = new List();
```

Can i make this list of User objects as result of execution SLQ CLR stored procedure ?
e.g. i want to get this

```
 
ID   UserName  UserPassword
1    Ted       SomePassword
2    Sam       Password2
3    Bill      dsdsd
```

```
[SqlProcedure]
public static void GetAllocations()
{
    // what here ??
}
```

P.S. Please do not advice me to use Sql functions. It does not suit me because it does not support output parameters

P.S.2 i will be very appreciated for any help !

Comment: Did you take a look to LINQ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create a virtual table with [SqlDataRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131105.aspx) and send it over the [Pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlcontext.pipe.aspx) property of [SqlContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlcontext.aspx) object:

```
[SqlProcedure]
public static void GetAllocations()
{
    // define table structure
    SqlDataRecord rec = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData[] {
        new SqlMetaData("ID", SqlDbType.Int),
        new SqlMetaData("UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar),
        new SqlMetaData("UserPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar),
    });

    // start sending and tell the pipe to use the created record
    SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart(rec);
    {
        // send items step by step
        foreach (User user in GetUsers())
        {
            int id = user.ID;
            string userName = user.UserName;
            string userPassword = user.UserPassword;

            // set values
            rec.SetSqlInt32(0, id);
            rec.SetSqlString(1, userName);
            rec.SetSqlString(2, userPassword);

            // send new record/row
            SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(rec);
        }
    }
    SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsEnd();    // finish sending
}
```

Comment: Marcel J. Kloubert.  I am really grateful for you !!! Thanks a much ! you save my life )